# create five button in flutter only one button should be pressed at once when clicked the button its color should change also refactor the widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

create five buttons in a row in flutter such that only one button should be pressed at once, when the button is pressed it color should change from white to red also the text color, also refactor the button widget.

i have used Material buttons but the problem is that when is press only one all the reset of the button pressed automatically and it is not unclicking again

Code

```
class SizeButton extends StatefulWidget {
  String text;
  bool small = false;
  bool medium = false;
  bool large = false;
  bool extraLarge = false;

  SizeButton({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  State<SizeButton> createState() => SizeButtonState();

}

class SizeButtonState extends State<SizeButton> {
  bool isClicked = false;

  void selectSize(String size) {
    setState(() {
      if (size == 'S') {
        widget.small = !widget.small;
        widget.medium = false;
        widget.large = false;
        widget.extraLarge = false;
      } else if (size == 'M') {
        widget.small = false;
        widget.medium = !widget.medium;
        widget.large = false;
        widget.extraLarge = false;
      } else if (size == 'L') {
        widget.small = false;
        widget.medium = false;
        widget.large = !widget.large;
        widget.extraLarge = false;
      } else if (size == 'XL') {
        widget.small = false;
        widget.medium = false;
        widget.large = false;
        widget.extraLarge= !widget.extraLarge;
      }
      isClicked = widget.small || widget.medium || widget.large || widget.extraLarge;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Container(
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border:Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.w),
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: isClicked ? Colors.pink : Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(widget.text,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.sp,
              color: isClicked ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        selectSize(widget.text);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: show us your code so we can see the mistakes and also what you've done so far and we can help you. trust me nobody here will write a full piece of code and paste it here for you show us what you've done so far what you expected and what is the result

Comment: Appreciate your comment, I have added the code, now the problem is that all button could be selected at once I just want to select one at a time

Answer (score 2):

[image: output]

Create dataModel class

```
class DataModel {
  String button;
  bool isSelected;

  DataModel(this.button, this.isSelected);
}
```

Place the widget class like below

```
class RecordChaseMoneyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RecordChaseMoneyPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<RecordChaseMoneyPage> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<RecordChaseMoneyPage> {
  List<DataModel> list = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    list.add(DataModel("1", false));
    list.add(DataModel("2", false));
    list.add(DataModel("3", false));
    list.add(DataModel("4", false));
    list.add(DataModel("5", false));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 30,
          child: ListView.separated(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (c, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      if (!list[index].isSelected) {
                        list[index].isSelected = true;
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 40,
                    color: list[index].isSelected ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
                  ),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (c, i) {
                return const SizedBox(width: 10);
              },
              itemCount: list.length),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

if want to select single item of list please change ontap method

```
setState(() {
                    list[index].isSelected = !list[index].isSelected;

                    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                      if (i != index) {
                        list[i].isSelected = false;
                      }
                    }

                  });
```

[image]

Comment: onTap: () {
  setState(() {
    // Unselect all the buttons
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (i != index) {
        list[i].isSelected = false;
      }
    }
    // Select the current button
    list[index].isSelected = true;
  });
},

Comment: it can select all buttons at once I want to select only one at a time

Comment: Your data is not in a sequential model , first you to put in model

Comment: Have you tried my snippet? @NumanAhmad

Comment: the code I posted for the onTap in the comment will work

Comment: @rahulVFlutterAndroid op don't want to select multiple buttons can you check my code and update your answer if it works?

Comment: @UsamaAltaf Means you want to select a button at one? from list

Comment: yes because in the question he wrote this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250865/discussion-between-rahulvflutterandroid-and-usama-altaf).

Comment: @UsamaAltaf can you please tap up on this answer

Comment: @NumanAhmad posted for both answer 
single item selection and multi-item selection

Comment: @UsamaAltaf posted for both case , single selection and multi selection

Answer (score 0):

Make a List of the Button

```
List button = [
'S',
'M',
'L',];
int selectedIndex = 0;
```

Add ListView Builder to show the buttons

```
Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          selectedIndex = index;
          print(button[index]);
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 20,
          width: 40,
          color: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
        ),
      );
    }),
```